# javascript .apply with variable function name

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm having problems calling a function with params, where the name of the function is stored in a variable.  I've been using `.call` and `.apply` to try to call the function, but I haven't had much success.

Here's what I've tried:

```
function slideup(){
//exec animation

}

Screen.prototype.init = function() {
    //has access to `this`, Screen is instantiated via constructor and passed the calling element 
    var self = this;

    self.animation = 'slideup';//this is a switch in my code with default val of 'slideup'  

    function hashChange(){

        self.animation.apply(self, [arg1,arg2]);
    }
}
```

If i replace `self.animation.apply` with `slideup.apply`... the function runs properly, but when I run `self.animation.apply` or `self[animation].apply`  I get `self.animation.apply is not a function`.  How can I use the string value stored in the variable to call the `slideup()` function, and pass it the proper args?  The idea is that the `self.animation` variable will store the name of a custom animation function, which can be overriden via the custom plugin's passed options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a string. You have to access the property named after this string :
`this[this.animation]();`

Comment: derp? I know I get a string, maybe a complete sentance would help explain what you mean?  I've tried `self[self.animation].apply` and `this[self.animation].apply` and still same error.

Comment: are you saying i need to access it from the level at which the string would return as a function?

Comment: I did something else to fix my function, but I'll accept the answer because it should have worked.  Something else in my code was causing it not to... likely to do with function scope.

Answer (score 1):

So Screen.animation is a string that is the name of a function . . . In that case, you need to use the square bracket notation to access the variable (in the appropriate scope). Assuming slideup is a global method, the code you are looking for is

```
window[self.animation].apply(self, [args]);
```

Comment: I considered doing exactly this... Screen.animation is inside the plugin scope, and while it can access the window, I'd rather it stay in the namespace.  so I could write something like `plugin[self.animation].apply()` I suppose.  It's a good suggestion, I just chose to change my function to a var, and return function names instead of strings in the switch statement.